# ASP.NET Pie Chart Labels

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a Pie chart with labels outside the chart, using just ASP.NET. Is there any way of doing this, without using C#?

I want the labels to have a line next to it which follows to the pie piece.

I would post an image but I dont have enough points to do so.

Comment: If you want to achieve this with out C#, you might try google api's chart or some other thrid party tools/apis - take a look https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Comment: Oh ok, so there is no way of doing it without using a third party?

Comment: Quick & Dirty approach is use a div with position and you can mention the height and width.. the disadvantage of this approach is position of the div panel vary according to the browser / device width & height. I would not use this approach

Comment: I've just tried to use the google api and its not as bad as I thought, is there a way for me to add my own datasource which comes directly from SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can check this

http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-create-dynamic-google-chart-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1031.aspx

MVC - [Google API chart in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535296/google-api-chart-in-asp-net-mvc)

[Pie chart with ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340935/pie-chart-with-asp-net)

http://www.c-sharplibrary.com/2014/02/how-to-create-charts-with-google-chart.html

HTH - Deepu